# Redirect in session not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

I am trying to do a basic login session in Laravel and I want the user not to be able to go to the login page once they are logged in. I tried to redirect it to the home page but it still shows my login page if I access it.

Do I have to add anything else?

This is the middleware that I used:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->path()=="login" && $request->session()->has('user'))
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using custom authentication? If you are using laravel auth is simple `Auth::check()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you've actually registered your middleware (whether in `app/Http/Kernel` or with the routes/controller. Also ensure you run the middleware after Laravel's normal HTTP middleware otherwise it may not have started the session/fetched the user yet.
2. I'm not sure `$request->session()->has('user')` is what you think it is - that's checking to see if the session has a key called `user`. You might want to check `$request->user()` instead.